# Handling a success and failure response Django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, response, jsonresponse

user is sending an api request to crate order along with  information in request body and after saving the data i am returning the order_id and access_token to the user.I have used few authentications also with using model.full_clean().Now i am stuck on the part to return success and failure status code and message along with the order_id and access_token.

```
@api_view(['POST'])
def orderdetails(request):  
    try:
        ACCESS_KEY_ID = request.META.get('HTTP_ACCESS_KEY_ID')
        ACCESS_KEY_SECRET = request.META.get('HTTP_ACCESS_KEY_SECRET')
        applications = Applications.objects.all()
        id=0
        for e in applications:
            if(e.ACCESS_KEY_ID==ACCESS_KEY_ID and e.ACCESS_KEY_SECRET==ACCESS_KEY_SECRET ):
                id = e.id+id
                print(id)
                break
        else:
            return Response({"Message":"Enter Valid Credentials"})
    except ValueError:
        return Response({"ACCESS":"DENIED"})
            
            
    if request.method == 'POST':       
        data=request.data
        print(data)
        orders = Orders(applications=Applications.objects.get(id=id),
        purpose_code = data['purpose_code'],
        amount=data['amount'],
        currency=data['currency'],
        note=data['note'],
        payer_name=data['payer_name'],
        payer_email=data['payer_email'],
        payer_phone_country_code=data['payer_phone_country_code'],
        payer_phone_number=data['payer_phone_number'],
        payee_name=data['payee_name'],
        payee_email=data['payee_email'],
        payee_phone_country_code=data['payee_phone_country_code'],
        payee_phone_number=data['payee_phone_number'],
        payee_pan = data['payee_pan'],
        payee_bank_account_holder_name=data['payee_bank_account_holder_name'],
        payee_bank_account_number=data['payee_bank_account_number'],
        payee_bank_account_ifsc=data['payee_bank_account_ifsc'],
        payee_bank_account_type=data['payee_bank_account_type'],
        payee_bank_account_beneficiary_identifier=data['payee_bank_account_beneficiary_identifier'],
        payment_collection_webhook_url=data['payment_collection_webhook_url'],
        payment_transfer_webhook_url=data['payment_transfer_webhook_url'],
        payment_gateway_code = data['payment_gateway_code'],
        isActive=data['isActive']
        )
        try:
            orders.full_clean()
        except ValidationError:
            return Response({"Error message":"invalid request body"})
                               
        else:
            orders.save()
            serializer = OrderSerializer(orders)
            order_id = serializer.data['id']
            access_token = serializer.data['access_token']
            return Response({"orderId":order_id,"accessToken":access_token})
```

required Success and failure response in the format bellow :
Success response (201/202) along with order_id and access_token
Failure response (422) along with message: "error message content"

Answer (score 1):

You could pass status code into Response object like below:

```
from rest_framework import status
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response

@api_view(['POST'])
def orderdetails(request): 
    return Response({'foo':'bar'}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can return different HTTP status codes in the response.

```py
# Importing status
from rest_framework import status

# To return a Successful response
# content is the data you return in the response, in your case its
content = {"orderId":order_id,"accessToken":access_token}
return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)


# To return a Bad Request response
content = {"Error message":"invalid request body"}
return Response(content, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

You can find all the different HTTP Status codes for DRF [here](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/status-codes/)

Comment: Thanks a lot @RanjanMP for posting the answer it is working perfect and i will definitely go through the HTTP Status codes for DRF.